# A question about the prime counting function

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, inequalities

I was playing around with the prime counting function and came across something that seemed correct to me, maybe it's already been proven but I don't know so I decided to ask here.

maybe a stupid question but whatever

Is $$\pi((n+1)^2) < \frac{(n+2)^2}{\ln((n+2)^2)}$$ for $n>0$?

Comment: Is there a reason this question is framed in terms of $n+1$ and not $n$ ($\pi(n^2) < \frac{(n+1)^2}{\ln((n+1)^2)}$)?

Comment: You wrote: "I still don't know how to write mathematical expressions". You can check whether the edits make this into the equation you wanted to write. You can find some useful pointers here: [How does one type mathematical formulas on this site?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3763)

Comment: This doesn't follow from fairly strong non-asymptotic bounds on the prims counting function, and I think it fails if $\pi(n^2) > \text{li}(n^2)$, see Skewes's number, so it should fail sometimes for big numbers. It might follow from weaker results on deviations of the prime counting function, I'm not sure

Answer (score 5):

A numerical calculation (in, say, Wolfram Alpha or Mathematica) shows that if $x \geq e$, then
$$\frac{(\sqrt{x}+1)^2}{2\log(1+\sqrt{x})}<\frac{x}{\log x}\Big(1+\frac{1}{\log x}+\frac{2}{(\log x)^2}\Big).$$
Moreover, [Pierre Dusart](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11139-016-9839-4) proved that if $x\geq 88,879$, then
$$
\frac{x}{\log x}\Big(1+\frac{1}{\log x}+\frac{2}{(\log x)^2}\Big)<\pi(x).
$$
Therefore, if $x\geq 88,879$, then
$$
\frac{(\sqrt{x}+1)^2}{2\log(1+\sqrt{x})}<\pi(x).
$$
Under the change of variables $n=\sqrt{x}-1$, we find that if $n\geq 297$, then
$$
\frac{(n+2)^2}{\log[(n+2)^2]}<\pi((n+1)^2).
$$
ADDED:  An additional numerical calculation shows that the only positive integers $n$ such that
$$\pi((n+1)^2)<\frac{(n+2)^2}{\log[(n+2)^2]}$$
are $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $7$, and $9$.